# What is "password" in classical Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary

The concept of passwords predates computers:
To gain access to, say, some heavily guarded premises, one may need to be able to say a secret phrase to the guards.
I would imagine this concept was not unheard of in antiquity.

What would a password like this be called in classical Latin?
My instinct is to use *signum* with a clarifying genitive like *admissus* or *accessus* or perhaps and adjective like *abditum*.
Was there a set expression for a password, or should one just explain the concept similarly to what I thought of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word itself was typically a *signum*, a sign, as in Plautus's *Miles Gloriosus*:

> M: cedo **signum**, si harunc Baccharum es.
> P: amat mulier quaedam quendam.
>
> *M: Give the **password**, if you're one of these Bacchants.*
> *P: A certain woman loves a certain man.*

But in military contexts, a nightly password was usually written on a little piece of material (*tessera*). So by metonymy, the password could be called a *tessera* too, as in Frontinus:

> Bello civili, cum Ategua urbs in Hispania Pompeianarum partium obsideretur, Maurus inter noctem tamquam Caesarianus tribuni cornicularius vigiles quosdam excitavit; ex quibus cum **tesseram** accepisset, alios excitans constantia fallaciae suae per medias Caesaris copias praesidium Pompei transduxit.
>
> *During the Civil War, when the city of Ategua in Spain (belonging to the Pompeians) was under seige, in the middle of the night, a certain Moor, [pretending to be] a tribute's adjutant, woke up some of the sentries, and after he had acquired **the password** from them [by pretending to check if they knew it], he woke up others, and by continuing this deceit, he managed to bring reinforcements for Pompey right through the middle of Caesar's troops.*

(WIP unfinished)